# How to read a list of dicts from txt file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text-files

I'm trying to get from a text file the dictionaries stored in a list

I searched for a `json` function, which can separate the string and save it in a list (a list of dictionaries), but I do not know if there is something like this.

**txt:**

```
[{"Principal": ["Jhon","Anderson","40"]}, {"Secretary": ["Marie","Garcia","29"]},{"Councilor": ["Alan", "Smith","33"]}]
```

**py code:**

```
stringvar=textfile.read()
```

// for or function below

```
dictionaries=json.loads(textfile.read())
otherlist=dictionaries
```

Comment: I think I was specific, the txt file looks just like it in a single line, what I want to achieve is to save it in several dictionaries that I will later put in a list,thanks

Comment: `dictionaries=json.loads(textfile.read())` already is a list of dictionaries. What do you miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to load the list of dictionaries from a `txt` file in Python, you can do it using the [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function from the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module, in order to evaluate the expression of the string in the file:

```
import ast

data = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as inFile:
    data = ast.literal_eval(inFile.read())
```

Comment: What's wrong with `json.loads`?

Comment: @mkiever `json.loads` should be the way of loading a dict from a file, as presented by Francesco Boi in the answer below. I just presented an alternative, thinking that the OP could not achieve the desired result using `json.load` as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all those kind of files are called json files.

You can open and read them as:

```
import json
f = open("results/results.json")
data = json.load(f)
```

Square brackets in json file defines an array, while curl brackets an object. The former will be converted to a list in python, the latter to dictionary.

So in your case `data` will be a list of dictionaries.

You can get the values and keys with the methods of the dictionary class `keys()`, `values()` or to get both `items()`.

To be complete a the elements of your json should have the same structure, the fields only should change. For example considering one element:

```
{"role"    : "Principal",
 "name:    : "Jhon",
 "surname. : "Anderson",
 "age":   40}
```

In this way you can iterate more easily through your json